# How to unselect line when clicking outside of any text

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a feature that selects the line on which user clicks.

```
    private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    
    if(richTextBox1.Lines.Length!=0)
    {
      int firstcharindex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
      int currentline = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstcharindex);
      string currentlinetext = richTextBox1.Lines[currentline];
      richTextBox1.Select(firstcharindex, currentlinetext.Length);
    }   
}
```

I want to achieve that when user clicks elsewhere (not on any line of text but still inside the textbox or anywhere else) the text will become unselected.

I tried using the GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine() method of RichTextBox but if i click outside of any text the previous value is remembered.

Comment: For the "still inside the textbox" you'll want to call `GetPositionFromCharIndex()` and compare that to the mouse position in `MouseEventArgs e`.  If the vertical distance is too great, then the user clicked in the empty space where there aren't any lines of text.  For the "or anywhere else", handle the `LostFocus` event.

Comment: You can check what `GetCharFromPosition(e.Location)` returns. If you click in a *empty space*, in a TextBox control, you get a `\n`. In that case, since users cannot willingly click on someting they don't see, the click occurred *outside* the text. BTW, never read the `Lines` property of a TextBoxBase derived Control. Also, you don't need it: you can get the next line index with `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(currentline + 1)`. If it returns `-1`, `currentline` is the last line, otherwise you have the last index (`+1` or `+2`) of the selection. The RTB Control only uses `\n`.